# How I can post my Facebook comments to my Drupal Site?

Tags: facebook, drupal

How I can post my Facebook comments to my Drupal Site?

Comment: hello Vadim! fb module, or fbconnect with direct calling.

Comment: Hello Nikit! FB module may publish a drupal-page as a facebook-page.  Facebook Connect module allows users to login on a Drupal website through the Facebook Connect API - using their Facebook login and password.  And I want my comments on Facebook copied to the pages of my drupal-site.

Comment: I am usually use fbconnect, using it's functions i am call directly facebook apis, more simpler than using FB module...

Answer (score 1):

Use facebooks comment plugin.

I am assuming you already have a facebook connect or something setup. Here's more info:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments

-Roozbeh

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Drupal [Facebook Comments Social Plugin module](https://www.drupal.org/project/facebook_comments) to do this. It integrates with Facebook's Comments plugin. It's fairly straightforward to setup but here's a [tutorial to integrating Drupal with Facebook comments](http://www.daymuse.com/blogs/drupal-facebook-comments-social-plugin-module-tutorial) using that module if you want a walkthrough.